# checking correlation between numeric and boolean in R

Tags: r, correlation

I'm beginner in R. I have learned how to check correlation between numeric data.

However I can not find details on how to check correlation between numeric and boolean type of data. Can anybody give me tips or guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for the [point-biserial correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient). Download the package `ltm`. It includes the function `biserial.cor`.

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rep(c(0,1), 5)

library(ltm)
biserial.cor(x,y)
#[1] -0.08279833
```

See `?biserial.cor` for details.

The result is slightly different from the one obtained with the built-in `cor` function:

```
cor(x,y)
#[1] 0.0872771
```

Answer (score 2):

This answers your question:

```
##x is logical, i.e. TRUE or FALSE
R> x = sample(c(T, F), 10, replace=10)
##y is numeric
R> y = runif(10)

##When we use correlation
##R converts TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.
R> cor(x, y)
[1] -0.5514
```

The obvious question is should you be doing this? Remember, correlation is testing for a **linear** relationship between x and y, i.e. as `x` increases `y` changes in a linear manner. This doesn't occur in your scenario. As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12496381/203420) by @Sven indicate, you want to use the Point-biserial correlation method.

---

If you data is a character vector, say:

```
x = c("M", "F")
```

then you would need to do an additional step:

```
x[x=="M"] = 1
x[x=="F"] = 1
```